# Full screen HTML page with scrolling enabeld to infinity in any size

Tags: html, css

How can I create full screen HTML page?

I try this

```css
height:100%
```

but dosn't works!

Comment: What is the [javascript] [reactjs] and [sass] tag doing here? :) This is only a css question

Comment: *Doesn't work* is a very vague term. You should post your HTML structure and related CSS classes. Better if you can make a JSFiddle

Comment: Also your title says “with sliding” I do not see anything related to sliding in the post

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just add code blow to your main style css file:

```
body {
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
  }
```

Comment: Obviously NOT. @nima this is terribly wrong.

Answer (score -1):

just work with devices views :

```
body{
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}
```